# Incorrect reasoning on sampling from marginals

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

Suppose we want to sample $X$ from a density $p(x) = e^{f(x)}$. My thought was that maybe we can introduce an auxiliary variable $Y$ such that $p(y|x) \propto e^{-\|(x,y)\|^2/2 - f(x)}$. Then the joint density would be $p(x,y) \propto  e^{-\|(x,y)\|^2/2}$ which is the normal density. Then to sample $X$, we can just sample $(X,Y)$ from the joint and then discard $Y$. However, this would just yield a normally distributed $X$. So I am wondering where my reasoning broke down.

**Edit:** Sorry, I realize now that if there was a marginal for some joint which is normal, then the marginal is itself normal.